How to install any App Store app directly from the Safari address bar?
In short: I want to install any App Store app directly from the Safari address bar.

Sometimes when I type the name of an App Store app in the Safari address bar, the Safari address bar will show me a dropdown with the option to install (or open) said app.
Mac App Store
Name of app                    Open
Category of app
Rating of app

For example:

However, when I type Xcode (Apple's own editor) it won't show the dropdown, but when I type appstore Xcode it will.
Why doesn't it show this dropdown for any App Store app (name) I type in the address bar?
Can I enable that — or is there a specific pattern I should type it in?

It is likely that you have already been to the app store and installed "Adaptivity." Have you? It seems like it otherwise there would not be a button that says "Open." The drop down in the Safari address bar is mostly (but not wholly) where you have gone before. E.G. your browsing history. So if you have never been to those other app stores, it is likely they won't show up in Safari history

The example in the screenshot was downloaded already of course, that's why wrote "install (or open)". Some apps that I have installed on iOS before will show up with a download icon — not text — instead of "Open/Install". However, this still doesn't happen for all apps, so I'm left to wonder what's causing the different dropdown behaviour…?
